# HERE MAP -V2 : java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground(), While performing TextAutosuggestionRequest

Tags: java, android

The code below was working fine, but suddenly I am getting a Java runtime exception while performing `TextAutosuggestionrequest`

This is my code:

```
    searchinfo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<AutoSuggest>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    listItems);

            searchitems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listItems.clear();

            if (!searchinfo.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                try {

                    TextAutoSuggestionRequest request1 = null;
                    if (map != null){
                        GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(SDLocation.getInstance().getLocation().getLatitude(), SDLocation.getInstance().getLocation().getLatitude());
                        request1 = new TextAutoSuggestionRequest(s.toString()).setSearchCenter(geo);
                    } else {
                        GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(SDLocation.getInstance().getLocation().getLatitude(), SDLocation.getInstance().getLocation().getLatitude());
                        request1 = new TextAutoSuggestionRequest(s.toString()).setSearchCenter(geo);
                    }


                    request1.execute(new ResultListener<List<AutoSuggest>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(List<AutoSuggest> autoSuggests, ErrorCode error) {
                            if (error == ErrorCode.NONE) {

                                    if (autoSuggests.size() > 0) {
                                        //searchlist = autoSuggests;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < autoSuggests.size(); i++) {
                                          listItems.add(autoSuggests.get(i).getTitle());


                                        }
                                    }
                                if (listItems!= null && !searchinfo.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    updatelist();
                                    searchitems.setAdapter(adapter);                                    }
                                   searchitems.setEnabled(true);
                            } else {
                               // CCLog.d("offline","error ");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    Log.d("MY",""+ex);
                    //Handle invalid create search request parameters
                } catch (UnintializedMapEngineException e) {
                    Log.d("MY",""+e);
                    //CCLog.d("offli;ne","error ")
                }
            }else{
                updatelist();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

And here is my error log

> 05-17 10:20:09.152 13938-14344/com.benz.event.navigation E/NETWORK:
>   Request:
>   https://places.hybrid.api.here.com/places/v1/meta/offline?app_id=sMeOyVw8rmO9kfHS4eSB&app_code=o-KMBFm4CNHIqv55LMKyBQ
>   Error: 400 Bad Request 05-17 10:20:09.321
>   13938-14748/com.benz.event.navigation E/art: No
>   (Ljava/lang/String;)V in
>   java.lang.Class 05-17 10:20:09.332
>   13938-14766/com.benz.event.navigation E/art: No
>   (Ljava/lang/String;)V in
>   java.lang.Class 05-17 10:20:09.336
>   13938-14748/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>                                                      Process: com.benz.event.navigation, PID: 13938
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Ljava/lang/AssertionError;.(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
>                                                          at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest.poll(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest.e(PlacesBaseRequest.java:62)
>                                                          at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest$b.a(PlacesBaseRequest.java:732)
>                                                          at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest$b.doInBackground(PlacesBaseRequest.java:713)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Any support will be really helpful.

Comment: You have a version mismatch.

Comment: Is the issue still occurring? If I go to the request URL I can see it is no longer returning 400 error.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis. after your comment i realized that i have made few changes in gradle which led to this behavior. issue is resolved now.

Comment: @Khan how did you solve it?